# Create a list of shared components of another list and a string?

Tags: python

I have two variables:

```
myList = [(0, 't'), (1, 'r'), (2, '_')]
newList = []
```

I want to create a new list, which includes tuples that have alphabet character inside. The output should be:

```
newList = [(0, 't'), (1, 'r')]
```

My initial thought is:

```
for thing in myList:
    if thing(1) in string.ascii_lowercase: #This line doesn't work.
        newList.append(thing)
```

I have 2 questions:

1. Please help me with the broken code. Can you tell me the name of the error, for a beginner, it's even hard to know the right word to search google.
2. Please give advice on naming things. Like in this example, how would you name `thing`?

Comment: What is the error you are getting with the code you posted? is it a `tuple is not callable`? If yes, you want to index the tuple, not call it, so `thing[1]`, not `thing(1)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change:

```
if thing(1) in string.ascii_lowercase:
```

to:

```
if thing[1] in string.ascii_lowercase:
```

Also make sure you have imported`string`.

You can rename thing to `list_tuple` or `my_list_object` for example. You will get good at naming eventually.

Answer (score 1):

The "Pythonic" way to accomplish your goal is as follows:

```
import string
newList = filter(lambda x: type(x) is tuple and x[1] in string.ascii_lowercase, myList)
```

Explanation:

`import string`: importing the string module to obtain a list of all alphabet

`filter(condition, iterable)`: an extremely useful, builtin, function of Python which allows you to filter out unwanted elements from a list (or any other iterable for that matter)

`lambda x`: an (usually simple) anonymous function defined at runtime which operates on a runtime variable x

`type(x) is tuple and x[1] in string.ascii_lowercase`: when operating on each element x in the iterable passed to `filter`, the lambda function first verifies that the element is indeed a tuple, and if so, checks if the first element is in the lowercased alphabet

Hope this helps